# Accessing nested objects in Vue

Tags: vue.js, object, binding

I am only able to access **currentView and subTask**, but not subTasks2. Although I'm following the same approach. I want to access the array of objects **branches and report** in the response. Any hint, please?

```json
[
    {
        "id": "sss",
        "name": "TestDemo",
        "visibility": "ss",
        "projects": [
            {
                "name": "ss",
                "branchs": [
                    {
                        "name": "master",
                        "state": "none",
                        "report": {
                            "branchName": "master",
                            "projectName": "ss",
                            "organizationName": "TestDemo",
                            "failedRuns": 0,
                            "totalRuns": 0,
                            "successRunsPercentage": 100
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Template vuejs (First two binds are working fine). I still want to access branchs and report

```html
  <div id="ID1">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="currentView in responseTest" :key="currentView.id" >
      {{ currentView.name }} - {{ currentView.visibility }}
      <ul>
        <li v-for="subTask in currentView.projects " :key="subTask.id" >
          {{ subTask.name }} - {{ subTask.branchs }}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="subTask2 in subTask.branchs " :key="subTask2.id" >
          {{ subTask2.name }} - {{ subTask2.state }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is that `subTask` is undefined in your third `v-for` due to incorrect nesting.

You can only access your variables assigned from the `v-for` inside child components of that element.

The element your `subTask2 in subTask.branchs` loop needs to be a child of the element that has the `subTask` variable.

For example:

```html
    <div id="ID1">
        <ul>
          <li v-for="currentView in responseTest" :key="currentView.id">
            {{ currentView.name }} - {{ currentView.visibility }}
            <ul>
              <li v-for="subTask in currentView.projects" :key="subTask.id">
                {{ subTask.name }} - {{ subTask.branchs }}
                <ul>
                  <li v-for="subTask2 in subTask.branchs" :key="subTask2.id">
                    {{ subTask2.name }} - {{ subTask2.state }}
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

You may need to play about with the structure and formatting to make it look right but that example should be runnable.